# Changing a TextView in another class from a Service

Tags: java, android, textview, android-service

I have two classes, one is a **standard activity**, the other a **service**. I would like the service to update a **TextView** (via `.setText()`) of the Activity on certain events that happen within the service.

I've tried to achieve this by programming something like a setter-method inside the Activity-Class, but TextViews don't accept a `static`-reference, and when I try invoking an instance of the Activity-class instead (via `MyActivityClassName aVariable = new MyActivityClassName();`), I get a **NullPointer Exception**, even though the View in questions is visible at the time of the call.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong :-)? It is probably more of a basic Java question than an Android-one, but since it might have to do with the nature of Android-services, I've still added the android-tag.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post the code for your service and view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like the service to update a
>   TextView (via .setText) of the
>   Activity on certain events that happen
>   within the service.

I would strongly recommend greater logical decoupling. Have the `Service` tell the `Activity` to update the `TextView`.

You can do that via a [broadcast `Intent`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/), or by having the `Activity` provide a listener object that the `Service` calls. In either case, be sure the Activity detaches from the service (unregisters the listener or broadcast `Intent` receiver), lest you cause a memory leak.

And, of course, this only works if the activity is actually running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link, I'll try it with a broadcast Intent!

Comment: Awesome, it works :-)! Thanks alot! Your sample was very helpful!